# Создание клавиш для игры змейка

Tags: javascript, html, button

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var grid = 16;
var count = 0;
var snake = {
x: 160,
y: 160,
dx: grid,
dy: 0,
cells: [],
maxCells: 4
};
var apple = {
x: 320,
y: 320
};
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
function loop() {
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
if (++count < 4) {
    return;
}
count = 0;
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
snake.x += snake.dx;
snake.y += snake.dy;
if (snake.x < 0) {
    snake.x = canvas.width - grid;
}
else if (snake.x >= canvas.width) {
    snake.x = 0;
}
if (snake.y < 0) {
    snake.y = canvas.height - grid;
}
else if (snake.y >= canvas.height) {
    snake.y = 0;
}
snake.cells.unshift({ x: snake.x, y: snake.y });
if (snake.cells.length > snake.maxCells) {
    snake.cells.pop();
}
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillRect(apple.x, apple.y, grid - 1, grid - 1);
context.fillStyle = 'green';
snake.cells.forEach(function (cell, index) {
    context.fillRect(cell.x, cell.y, grid - 1, grid - 1);
    if (cell.x === apple.x && cell.y === apple.y) {
        snake.maxCells++;
        apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
        apple.y = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
    }
    for (var i = index + 1; i < snake.cells.length; i++) {
        if (cell.x === snake.cells[i].x && cell.y === snake.cells[i].y) {
            snake.x = 160;
            snake.y = 160;
            snake.cells = [];
            snake.maxCells = 4;
            snake.dx = grid;
            snake.dy = 0;
            apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
            apple.y = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
        }
    }
});
}
//Нажатие клавиш
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
//На клавиатуре нажата стрелка влево
if (e.which === 37 && snake.dx === 0) {
    snake.dx = -grid;
    snake.dy = 0;
}
//На клавиатуре нажата стрелка вверх
else if (e.which === 38 && snake.dy === 0) {
    snake.dy = -grid;
    snake.dx = 0;
}
//На клавиатуре нажата стрелка вправо
else if (e.which === 39 && snake.dx === 0) {
    snake.dx = grid;
    snake.dy = 0;
}
//На клавиатуре нажата стрелка вниз
else if (e.which === 40 && snake.dy === 0) {
    snake.dy = grid;
    snake.dx = 0;
}
});
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

/*Задаём глобальные параметры*/
body {
    background: black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

/*Делаем границу вокруг игрового поля*/
canvas {
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="game"></canvas>
//Здесь нужно добавить кнопки и занести в них функцию с нажатием клавиш как на клавиатуре
```

Это код, и мне нужно добавить кнопки, которыми можно будет управлять игрой.

Answer (score 1):

У вас ведь уже реализована функция для keydown, которая работает на основе значения `which` в объекте-первого параметра функции. Как-раз его и можно вызывать при клике, подсунув объект вида `функция({ which: 37 })`

Изменения отмечены комментами:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var grid = 16;
var count = 0;
var snake = {
  x: 160,
  y: 160,
  dx: grid,
  dy: 0,
  cells: [],
  maxCells: 4
};
var apple = {
  x: 320,
  y: 320
};

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  if (++count < 4) {
    return;
  }
  count = 0;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  snake.x += snake.dx;
  snake.y += snake.dy;
  if (snake.x < 0) {
    snake.x = canvas.width - grid;
  } else if (snake.x >= canvas.width) {
    snake.x = 0;
  }
  if (snake.y < 0) {
    snake.y = canvas.height - grid;
  } else if (snake.y >= canvas.height) {
    snake.y = 0;
  }
  snake.cells.unshift({
    x: snake.x,
    y: snake.y
  });
  if (snake.cells.length > snake.maxCells) {
    snake.cells.pop();
  }
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fillRect(apple.x, apple.y, grid - 1, grid - 1);
  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  snake.cells.forEach(function(cell, index) {
    context.fillRect(cell.x, cell.y, grid - 1, grid - 1);
    if (cell.x === apple.x && cell.y === apple.y) {
      snake.maxCells++;
      apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
      apple.y = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
    }
    for (var i = index + 1; i < snake.cells.length; i++) {
      if (cell.x === snake.cells[i].x && cell.y === snake.cells[i].y) {
        snake.x = 160;
        snake.y = 160;
        snake.cells = [];
        snake.maxCells = 4;
        snake.dx = grid;
        snake.dy = 0;
        apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
        apple.y = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
      }
    }
  });
}

requestAnimationFrame(loop);

/***/
const ARROW = { // Собрал значения в объект, чтобы не использовать непонятные числа
  LEFT: 37,
  UP: 38,
  RIGHT: 39,
  DOWN: 40,
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", changeSnakeDirection);

Object.keys(ARROW).forEach(direction => {
  // direction - это строки "LEFT", "UP", "RIGHT"...
  
  id(direction.toLowerCase()).addEventListener("click", function() {
    changeSnakeDirection({ which: ARROW[direction] });
    // ARROW[direction] — 37 / 38 / 39 / 40
  });
});

/***/
// Вынес функцию сюда, вызывается и на keydown, и на click;
function changeSnakeDirection(e) {

  if (e.which === ARROW.LEFT && snake.dx === 0) {
    snake.dx = -grid;
    snake.dy = 0;
  }
  
  else if (e.which === ARROW.UP && snake.dy === 0) {
    snake.dy = -grid;
    snake.dx = 0;
  }
  
  else if (e.which === ARROW.RIGHT && snake.dx === 0) {
    snake.dx = grid;
    snake.dy = 0;
  }
  
  else if (e.which === ARROW.DOWN && snake.dy === 0) {
    snake.dy = grid;
    snake.dx = 0;
  }
}

function id(str) {
  return document.getElementById(str);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.buttons button {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

#left  { top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
#right { top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; }
#up    { right: 0; left: 0; top: 0; }
#down  { right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="left">◄</button>
  <button id="right">►</button>
  
  <button id="up">▲</button>
  <button id="down">▼</button>
</div>

<canvas width="400" height="400" id="game"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так например

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var grid = 16;
  var count = 0;
  var snake = {
    x: 160,
    y: 160,
    dx: grid,
    dy: 0,
    cells: [],
    maxCells: 4
  };
  var apple = {
    x: 320,
    y: 320
  };

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }

  function loop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    if (++count < 4) {
      return;
    }
    count = 0;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    snake.x += snake.dx;
    snake.y += snake.dy;
    if (snake.x < 0) {
      snake.x = canvas.width - grid;
    } else if (snake.x >= canvas.width) {
      snake.x = 0;
    }
    if (snake.y < 0) {
      snake.y = canvas.height - grid;
    } else if (snake.y >= canvas.height) {
      snake.y = 0;
    }
    snake.cells.unshift({
      x: snake.x,
      y: snake.y
    });
    if (snake.cells.length > snake.maxCells) {
      snake.cells.pop();
    }
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.fillRect(apple.x, apple.y, grid - 1, grid - 1);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    snake.cells.forEach(function(cell, index) {
      context.fillRect(cell.x, cell.y, grid - 1, grid - 1);
      if (cell.x === apple.x && cell.y === apple.y) {
        snake.maxCells++;
        apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
        apple.y = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
      }
      for (var i = index + 1; i < snake.cells.length; i++) {
        if (cell.x === snake.cells[i].x && cell.y === snake.cells[i].y) {
          snake.x = 160;
          snake.y = 160;
          snake.cells = [];
          snake.maxCells = 4;
          snake.dx = grid;
          snake.dy = 0;
          apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
          apple.y = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
        }
      }
    });
  }


  function wayToMove(cX, cY) {
    snake.dx = cX;
    snake.dy = cY;
  }


  //Нажатие клавиш
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    //На клавиатуре нажата стрелка влево
    if (e["which"] === 37 && snake.dx === 0) {
      wayToMove(-grid, 0);
    }
    //На клавиатуре нажата стрелка вверх
    else if (e["which"] === 38 && snake.dy === 0) {
      wayToMove(0, -grid);
    }
    //На клавиатуре нажата стрелка вправо
    else if (e["which"] === 39 && snake.dx === 0) {
      wayToMove(grid, 0);
    }
    //На клавиатуре нажата стрелка вниз
    else if (e["which"] === 40 && snake.dy === 0) {
      wayToMove(0, grid);
    }
  });




  var upBtn = document.getElementById("btn-up"),
    downBtn = document.getElementById("btn-down"),
    leftBtn = document.getElementById("btn-left"),
    rightBtn = document.getElementById("btn-right");

  upBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    (snake.dy === 0) ? wayToMove(0, -grid): false;
  });
  downBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    (snake.dy === 0) ? wayToMove(0, grid): false;
  });
  leftBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    (snake.dx === 0) ? wayToMove(-grid, 0): false;
  });
  rightBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    (snake.dx === 0) ? wayToMove(grid, 0): false;
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}


/*Задаём глобальные параметры*/

body {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: #f00;
  color: #f00;
}

.btn:first-child {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.btn:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="game"></canvas>
<div class="buttons">
  <div id="btn-up" class="btn">&uarr;</div>
  <div id="btn-left" class="btn">&larr;</div>
  <div id="btn-down" class="btn">&darr;</div>
  <div id="btn-right" class="btn">&rarr;</div>
</div>
```